# Configure a freeRadius server with dhcp function

Tags: debian, configuration, dhcp, radius

I have installed a freeradius server on a debian machine and it is working correctly.

I want to configure my freeradius server to provide IP addresses for the authenticated users!

Can any one tell me how can I do that? what are the configuration files that I need to modify?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at this [tutorial](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/dhcp-for-static-ip-allocation)?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, but it didn't work for me, it does'nt provide many details. Sure I'm missing something in my configuration. Do you know any better tutorial?

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Comment: Not really, I managed to use an LDAP server to affect a static IP using the option Framed-IP-Address.

Comment: There were DHCP related bugs, I follow the dev list. Which FR version have you tried to configure?